# How can I implement MongoDB on Angular 9?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb

I'd like to know how to implement MongoDB to Angular 9 for Inserting, Deleting and updating data. I heard it can be done using Node JS.

I need some sample code for an academic project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](https://medium.com/@vsvaibhav2016/create-crud-application-in-express-js-9b88a5a94299) is a great step towards learning NodeJS express and Mongo DB connection with CRUD operations.

The author has mentioned step by step procedure for DB operation with Node.
And to combine it with Angular, you can create something to call CRUD APIs of your Node application which will handle the DB connection.